# Unable to initialize "document" in this code

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to call a javascript function from java using selenium web driver.

here is the code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("C:\\KIRAN\\TrialAndError.htm"); // The html page is loaded here

// Following is the way i am trying to run the javascript

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");

String script = "function getInputIds(param) {  
                          print(\"inside getInputIds\");    
                          var elems = document.form[0].elements;    
                          var length = elems.length;    
                          var arr = new Array();  
                          var match_found = 0;  
                          for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {      
                               match_found = elems[i].id.match(/order_unit_line_rate_\\d+_unit/);       
                               if (match_found) {           
                                  arr.push(elems[i].id);        
                               }    
                           }    
                           print(elems[1].id);}";

engine.eval(script);

Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine; 

inv.invokeFunction("getInputIds", "Scripting!!" );
```

But this the error i get when i run this code

```
inside getInputIdsException : javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

Please help me run this piece of code by initializing the "document" object.

Also let me know if it is possible to return the array "arr" to be used in the java file outside the javascript.

Thanks in Advance
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any need to use ScriptEngine when the driver instance has it built in.

From the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?)

You can execute Javascript by casting the WebDriver instance to a JavascriptExecutor. In Java, this looks like:

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return document.title");
```

Comment: Hi epascarello .. thanks for the quick response. I tried the code wic u gave in the above comment, but still no luck :( this is what I tried    
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     js.executeScript("C:\\QA\\Selenium\\workspace\\Module-NewServiceOrder\\src\\momentum\\getInputIds.js","");

Comment: i also have one more question .

Comment: @KiranKoundinya You should insert the script, not the file name. If you want to load the script from a file, use [`FileUtils.readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) from Apache Commons IO, or [`Files.toString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from Guava.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("C:\\QA\\Selenium\\workspace\\Module-NewServiceOrder\\src\\momentum\\getInputIds.js","");
```

But this the result

```
Exception : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 16:53:24'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_03'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: e2a43e1d-0eec-4640-ac0f-d72a485d98f8

I wasn't even able to enter into the function

Comment: You should insert the script, not the file name. If you want to load the script from a file, use [`FileUtils.readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) from Apache Commons IO, or [`Files.toString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from Guava.